# Delphi 2007 ZeosLib 6.6 Mysql 4.1 Transaction lock table from other client

Tags: mysql, delphi, transactions, locking, zeos

The situation is this. I have two client programs that connect to the same mysql db on a server. When I run an operation on a table in the following way

```
        ZCon.TransactIsolationlevel := tiSerializable;
        ZCon.AutoCommit := true;
        ZCon.StartTransaction;
        try
          ZQGeneral.Close;
          ZQGeneral.SQL.Clear;

          ZQGeneral.SQL.Add('UPDATE table1 SET field1 = 1 WHERE id = 2');
          ZQGeneral.ExecSQL;
          ZQGeneral.Close;


          ZCon.Commit;
          ZCon.TransactIsolationlevel := tinone;
          ZCon.AutoCommit := False;

        except
          ZCon.Rollback;
          ZCon.TransactIsolationlevel := tinone;
          ZCon.AutoCommit := False;
        end;
```

the table 1 is blocked and will not unlock until the client disconnect that has completed the transaction. On the client who first started a transaction the table is also writeable but from the other client is read-only.
I gave to msyql account all the privileges for not mistaken, I also tried to send a UNLOCK tables after transaction operation but it did not help.
I double-checked the source of the program to make sure I did not forget some ZQuery open but nothing to scruples.
Why commit do not unlock table1 for other client?

I also tryed tiReadCommited and tiUnreadCommited with the same behavior.
I also tryed to upgrade Zeos to version 7.2 and change mysql with version 5 with then same result. Ah, I use InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solutions. Set autocommit to true and transactisoltionlevel to tiserializable before connection to mysql and not change it at runtime and then use implicit starttransaction when need.